# FatFree routing doesn't work with Virtual Host

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I developed an application with FatFree framework on Apache on Ubuntu and it was working fine. I was not using any Virtual Host configuration and the index.php was in the server root.

Now, I have created a virtual host and I want to work on a new project as well and I moved the previous project to a subfolder of the server root. I have correctly done the virtual host configuration.

The problem -

I have many routes defined in index.php. The home route, `F3::route('GET /', 'Main->front_page')` is being mapped correctly so the first page comes up fine. However, any other route does not match. Specifically, I have a route `F3::route('GET /captcha', 'Main->security_code')` which gives me a 500 error.

The log for the error in the apache error log is as follows -

```
[Thu Aug 16 12:48:49 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Thu Aug 16 12:48:49 2012] [debug] core.c(3112): [client 127.0.0.1] r->uri = /oresoft/index.php
[Thu Aug 16 12:48:49 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /oresoft/index.php
[Thu Aug 16 12:48:49 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /oresoft/index.php
[Thu Aug 16 12:48:49 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /oresoft/index.php
[Thu Aug 16 12:48:49 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /oresoft/index.php
[Thu Aug 16 12:48:49 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /oresoft/index.php
[Thu Aug 16 12:48:49 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /oresoft/index.php
[Thu Aug 16 12:48:49 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /oresoft/index.php
[Thu Aug 16 12:48:49 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /oresoft/index.php
[Thu Aug 16 12:48:49 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /oresoft/index.php
[Thu Aug 16 12:48:49 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /captcha
[Thu Aug 16 12:48:49 2012] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 127.0.0.1] Zlib: Compressed 624 to 382 : URL /oresoft/index.php
```

Am I missing something here? How come one route is matching while not the others?

Following is my .htaccess file which is in the same folder as `index.php` and is in the subfolder `/oresoft` of `/var/www`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /oresoft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
```

This is the same htaccess file which I had earlier. I just moved this into the subfolder and changed the `RewriteBase`.

Comment: Show us your .htaccess file. It's a critical component.

Comment: Edited the question and included the contents of htaccess file.

Comment: Do you have `Options +FollowSymLinks` in your `VirtualHost *` section?

Comment: Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews (yes, I have it)

Comment: It seems like the `/captcha` route is rerouting back to `index.php`. Perhaps it will help us a lot more if you posted the relevant contents of `index.php` and the `Main` class so we remove the guesswork.

Comment: Ok, so in `index.php`, I have a line to autoload the controller classes like `F3::set('AUTOLOAD', 'oresoft_platform/inc')`; [Please note that in the subfolder where `index.php` is located there is a folder `oresoft_platform` where is the complete directory structure]. I wrote a new route `F3::route('GET /testroute', 'Main->test_route');` and in `inc/main.php` the handler is just a plain `echo`. I am getting the same error. Please let me know if you need any specific information other than this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15413/discussion-between-siddharth-and-stillstanding)

Comment: Also check chown and chmod of /tmp